# How to std::bind a smart pointer return method?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, stdbind

So I have this method inside my `Bar` class:

```
std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> Bar::getStuff() const
{
   //...
}
```

And I have my callback typedef:

```
typedef std::function<void()> Callback;

void Foo::registerCallback(const Callback& callback)
{
    //...
}
```

And now I want to use `std::bind` on this method, like:

```
Foo foo;
Bar bar; //I create an instance of an Bar, called bar. 

foo.registerCallback(std::bind(&Bar::getStuff, std::ref(bar))); //<--- ERROR!!!!
```

**ERROR:**

```
error C2562: 'std::_Callable_obj<std::_Bind<true,std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>,std::_Pmf_wrap<std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> (__thiscall Bar::* )(void)
```

If I want to use a void method, it's ok. But I need to use the `getStuff()` method, which will return me a `smart pointer` to a sf::Sprite thing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `std::bind(&Bar::getStuff, &bar)` instead, IIRC, `std::ref` cannot be used in `INVOKE`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `bind` unwraps `reference_wrapper`s, independent of `INVOKE`. (And [LWG 2219](http://wg21.link/lwg2219) made `INVOKE` work with them anyway.)

Comment: Which version of MSVC is this?

Comment: VS C++ 2012 with the compiler: "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012)"

Comment: @T.C. oh, so it does, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you are using c++11, why not a lambda?

```
foo.registerCallback([&bar]() { bar.getStuff(); });
```

Comment: @Nicol, I left it as copy, as normally you'd want the lifetime to be guaranteed (as it's a callback.) so assuming `bar` is in a `shared_ptr` - which would be the correct model...

Comment: Yes, but his code bound it explicitly using `std::ref`. If he wanted a copy, he would have just stuck the value in there. Obviously, it's a bad idea to use a reference, but that's what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::bind` works with `std::reference_wrapper`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417892/5470596). Your error comes from the way you call it. `Bar::getStuff` returns something you try to discard. You can only discard things in discard expressions and statements.

#### A solution

```
template<class Callable>
auto discard_callable(Callable&& callable)
{ return [=]() { (void) callable(); }; }
```

You could use it like this:

```
foo.registerCallback(discard_callable(
    std::bind(&Bar::getStuff, std::cref(bar))
));
```

#### MCVE

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct Butler
{
    std::string say() const { return "Welcome home, Sir."; }
};

template<class Callable>
auto discard_callable(Callable&& callable)
{ return [=]() { (void) callable(); }; }

int main()
{
    Butler igor;
    std::function<void()> welcome = discard_callable(std::bind(&Butler::say, std::ref(igor))); // error without discard
    welcome();
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2716f0bdf882dfcc)