# How is this shared_ptr automatically converted to a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I'm studying `enable_shared_from_this` of C++11 now; one example made me confused: how the `shared_ptr` type returned by `shared_from_this()` can convert to this raw pointer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Bar {
    Bar(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

struct Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo\n"; }

    std::shared_ptr<Bar> getBar(int a)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Bar> pb(
            new Bar{a}, std::bind(&Foo::showInfo, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1)
        );
        return pb;
    }

    void showInfo(Bar *pb)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::showInfo()\n";
        delete pb;
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pf(new Foo);
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> pb = pf->getBar(10);
    std::cout << "pf use_count: " << pf.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) being smart, not the pointer.

> As described in Callable, when invoking a pointer to non-static member function or pointer to non-static data member, the first argument has to be a reference or pointer (including, possibly, smart pointer such as std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr) to an object whose member will be accessed.

`bind` is implemented so it can accept a smart pointer in lieu of a raw pointer.

You can see in the [glibc++ implementation than `bind` internally calls `invoke`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional#L400):

```
  // Call unqualified
  template<typename _Result, typename... _Args, std::size_t... _Indexes>
_Result
__call(tuple<_Args...>&& __args, _Index_tuple<_Indexes...>)
{
  return std::__invoke(_M_f,
      _Mu<_Bound_args>()(std::get<_Indexes>(_M_bound_args), __args)...
      );
}
```

And [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) works with smart things (pointers, [reference wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54418456/5470596), etc.) out-of-the-box:

> `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is defined as follows:
>
> If `f` is a pointer to member function of class `T`:
>
> - If `std::is_base_of<T, std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>>::value` is true, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)`
> - If `std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>` is a specialization of `std::reference_wrapper`, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `(t1.get().*f)(t2, ..., tN)`
> - **If `t1` does not satisfy the previous items, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)`**.

Comment: thanks a lot, I figure out the reason, this is the std::invoke()'s rule. this first argument does not always be this raw pointer, may be reference or smart pointer.